# How to fix "Org or space not found" error while creating toolchain in IBM cloud?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying to deploy Cloud Foundry application to IBM cloud. When I try to create "Toolchain" and select Region under "Delivery Pipeline", I don't get any value under "Organization" label.

I went through IBM cloud's deployment description page and tried to change the region from "Frankfurt" to "Dallas" as recommended.
I am using Lite account, therefore, cannot create more than one organization.
Please note that I already have one organization created which is not getting discovered.

I expect the "Organization" and "Space" column to populate automatically once the region is selected.

Comment: In which region are your org / space and in which the toolchain?

Comment: I got "Frankfurt" as the closest region, but there was no organization discoverable for this region. After reading the IBM cloud's document, I reset it to "Dallas". The same has been mentioned in the following link: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/deploy-your-first-app-to-ibm-cloud/

Comment: Org name being: OmUniyal. Please let me know if i understood your question correctly.

Comment: What is your home region? Is that the region where you tried to deploy the app using the toolchain? Some services operate on a global level, others are limited to a region. You need to make sure that everything is accessible in your "home" region

Comment: That's it. It didn't work for any other region but London. Thank you so much. I guess the auto-detected location is something not to rely upon. Appreciate your valuable responses.

Comment: I figured the default location (at the time of IBM cloud account creation) was United Kingdom, but since I am operating from Asia Pacific, the closest region detected was from Asia Pacific and not from United Kingdom.

Answer (score 5):

> I solved it by putting region correctly. My organization belonged to region "United Kingdom" so I had to select region "London" while creating a toolchain.

Make sure you have done the following steps correctly.

### 1. Note down Organization name, Region, and Space name from a link given below.

Go to this link https://cloud.ibm.com/account/cloud-foundry and then click on the organization name. After that you will see this page then notes these things.

[image]

### 2: Go to the link given below to create toolchain and on the page put everything on red marking below that you noted above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@OmUniyal, If you're just starting out working with toolchains, I would recommend creating the toolchain in a resource group rather than an organization.  Although there is no planned date, organization based toolchains will eventually be migrated to resource group based ones.  Functionally toolchains in orgs or resource groups are basically the same, it's just the "container" holding them.